# Stealing "remember me" cookies a valid threat?

Tags: security, cookies

I'm using SSL to transmit all data. HTTP is completely disabled. Short of malware, or accessing someones physical machine (both of which are very hard to prevent from server side), I don't see how an attacker could steal a login cookie.

Thus, is it okay to not worry about stealing a login cookie?

The complexity to properly implement a non-stealable login cookie, that still allows users to have sessions across different browsers and different machines is higher than the material it's safe-guarding.

Thus, I believe it's okay to not safe guard against copy and pasting cookie data from machine to machine.

Is this a valid trade off, or am I forgetting something critical here.

Comment: The OWASP people have some session cookie advice [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Cookies)

Comment: Oh, I meant to link to OWASP--good call, @pd40.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to ensure that you have the `Secure` flag set on your cookie, because you can't generally prevent people from attempting to access your site over non-SSL. Otherwise, I believe you should be OK.

That said, I'd suggest taking reasonable precautions. For example:

- Never include any data in cookies or on the wire that could be used to derive the user's password.
- If possible, set the `HttpOnly` flag on sensitive cookies so that any potentially-untrusted JavaScript can't steal them.

Comment: If I attempt to access site via HTTP, it will attempt to send the login cookie?

Comment: If you don't set the Secure flag, then, yes. Normally browsers send cookies on any request that matches the domain and path, regardless of scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it's a valid threat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

A "remember me" cookie places the security of your web service out of your control, by definition. Now, in general, anyone (especially a sophisticated attacker) who can hijack that cookie can log in as that user.

Let's take a real-world example: Google uses similar cookies for its services. You can be logged in for weeks at a time. From what I have observed, the way it mitigates cookie-theft attacks is by invalidating the cookie if they detect suspicious activity on the server side. For example, if I'm usually logged in from California, and I suddenly log in from another state/country (or have concurrent sessions from somewhere else!) I might be logged out and forced to re-authenticate. Not fool-proof, of course, but usage patterns could be used to thwart some attacks.

Also, remember that a cookie is going to be browser-specific. For example, if the browser fingerprint was used to determine that the user just logged in from a different OS/browser/etc, that might be a good time to invalidate the cookie. Maybe you could get fancy and allow a certain amount of leeway if a browser's minor version is upgrade, but flag it if the browser version ever gets *downgraded*.

Comment: > "Anyone (especially a sophisticated attacker) who can hijack that cookie can log in as that user." Another way to phrase my question is: are there other ways programattic ways an attacker can hijack a session. Are they all worth guarding against?

Comment: Yeah, if you read the wiki page, you'll see other methods with varying degrees of sophistication, such as SSL man-in-the-middle attacks, etc. But honestly, it sounds to me like in your case they aren't worth guarding against. If they were, you wouldn't be talking about having a "remember me" cookie, because you'd want your users to log in with their password each time. You'd be talking about maybe using SSL client certificates to authenticate your clients. But you're talking about user convenience. So it's probably not worth it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSL-MITM. From my understanding of MITM attacks, SSL completely prevents MITM.

Comment: Normally, yes. If you have a self-signed certificate on the server, a misconfigured client, a user who clicks through SSL warnings, a trick like [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/), or maybe you've got a certificate trusted by a CA the client trusts (common in some workplaces and often used to proxy and spy on SSL traffic) or have placed your own CA on the client somehow... etc. No security is ever 100%.

Comment: Oh I agree. There is no such thing as absolute security. But I was under the impression that SSL is currently considered good enough to protect against MITM. I just wasn't aware if I really had to worry about SSL-MITM. It sounds like no, because 1) the stuff we're doing isn't that critical and 2) the attacks are some what sophisticated (safe for Johnny Q. DumbDumb who clicks ignore SSL errors)

Comment: Make sure that your site is locked down against XSS, as any XSS flaw can also make it possible for a MITM attack to leverage this vulnerability. Especially check that there are no exploits possible by modifying the cookie value (e.g. XSS or SQL injection).